# Handling input events in a MetalKit application

Tags: objective-c, macos, input, metal, metalkit

I created an application on OS X in Xcode using "Game" template that uses MetalKit. How do I handle input events like keyDown and keyUp? I tried adding

```
- (void)keyDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    NSLog( @"Key down\n" );
}

- (void)keyUp:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    NSLog( @"Key up\n" );
}
```

into AppDelegate and GameViewController but they are not called when I press a key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are not using `MetalKit`, you would need to create a view that is a subclass of `NSView` and implement the following methods therein:

```
- (void)keyDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    NSLog(@"onKeyDown Detected; Merry Christmas, by the way.");
}

- (BOOL)acceptsFirstResponder
{
    return YES;
}
```

If you're using `MetalKit`, however, you would do the same and would implement the aforementioned methods in a view subclassing `MTKView` there instead.

I have tested on both versions; and `keyDown` was called when a key was pressed.

Comment: Yup. If you're used to iOS development you may be surprised by this — in OS X, view controllers are not part of the [responder chain](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/EventArchitecture/EventArchitecture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i-CH3-SW11) like they are in iOS. And to receive key events, a view needs to be the first responder.

Comment: I had the same problem, tried the same work-arounds, and indeed subclassing MTKView solved it.  Now I have a puzzle; for the heck of it, got rid of the subclass, reverted to the original MTKView but now 'keyDown' in GameViewController works!  And I'm not overriding 'acceptsFirstResponder' anywhere!

Comment: ...and just as mysteriously, 10 hours and many compiles+runs later, it stopped working.  Xcode gremlins no doubt.

Answer (score 4):

For Swift apps, add these to your MTKView subclass:

```
// yes, this MUST be here.
override var acceptsFirstResponder: Bool { 
    return true 
}
override func keyDown(with theEvent: NSEvent) {
    // do something 
}
override func keyUp(with theEvent: NSEvent) {
    // do something 
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, tested on macOS Big Sur 11.3.1 (20E241) + Xcode Version 12.5 (12E262).

Answer (score 2):

As stated: you must subclass MTKView and handle keyDown in the subclass.
Also remember to set the view's class in Storyboard from MTKView to the subclass.

This is the way to get rid of those nasty beeps in a MTKView (due to unhandled keyDown).

But also as stated in the comments: if you reset the class in Storyboard to MTKView, keyDown keeps being handled (and there are no beeps). Odd.

I never got it to work without subclassing as suggested in one of the answers. How do you get a pointer to GameViewController at that stage?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I got keyboard input in my MetalKit application without subclassing `MTKView`.

I implemented `keyDown` in GameViewController.mm:

```
- (void)keyDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    NSLog(@"keyDown Detected");
}

- (BOOL)acceptsFirstResponder
{
    return YES;
}
```

In my AppDelegate.m I call `[[ [myViewController view] window ] makeFirstResponder:myViewController];` in `applicationDidFinishLaunching` where `myViewController` points to my GameViewController instance.